# Anyone want to tell me why my pygame code lags while using pygame Vectors?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm following a p5.js tutorial from The Coding Train (but writing in Python) for this firework-esque simulator, but when I more than one "firework" on the screen, the program starts to lag until its taken off, is pygame just inherently slow at drawing the pygame Vectors or is there something wrong with my code?

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.math import Vector2
pygame.init()
window = (400,300)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(window)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
gravity = Vector2(0,0.2)
fireworks = []
class Particle:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.pos = Vector2(self.x,self.y)
        self.vel = Vector2(0,random.randrange(-12,-8))
        self.acc = Vector2(0,0)

    def applyForce(self,force):
        self.acc += force

    def update(self):
        self.vel += self.acc
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.acc *= 0

    def show(self):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, (0,0,0), (self.pos.x,self.pos.y,4,4))
        clock.tick(60)
class Firework:
    def __init__(self):
        self.firework = Particle(random.randrange(0,window[0]),window[1])

    def update(self):
        if self.firework:
            self.firework.applyForce(gravity)
            self.firework.update()
            if self.firework.vel.y >= 0:
                self.firework = None

    def show(self):
        if self.firework:
            self.firework.show()




def draw():
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    if random.uniform(0,1) < .1:
        fireworks.append(Firework())
    for firework in fireworks:
        firework.update()
        firework.show()
    pygame.display.update()



def main():

    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
        draw()
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame. It will compute how many milliseconds have passed since the previous call.

However, you do not call `tick()` once per frame, but once per particle. This delays the game for each particle. The more particles you have, the more the game delays.

Remove `clock.tick(60)` from `Particle.show`.

```py
class Particle:
    # [...]

    def show(self):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, (0,0,0), (self.pos.x,self.pos.y,4,4))
        # clock.tick(60) <--- DELETE
```

Call it once in the `draw` function or the main application loop:

```py
def main():

    running = True
    while running:
        
        clock.tick(60) # <--- ADD
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
        draw()
```

[image]